# How to wait for xtext service to complete before executing code

Tags: editor, dsl, xtext, xtend

I am using the Xtext web editor framework and am having an issue with code being executed before its preconditions have been run. For instance, when I update my document It calls into the `XtextServlet` `doService` method. I have subclassed the `XtextServlet` class and overridden the `doService` method like this:

```
override doService(XtextServiceDispatcher.ServiceDescriptor service, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super.doService(service, response)
        switch (service.context.getParameter("serviceType")) {
            case "update": {
                // Execute other code
            }
    }
```

This other code that I am running relies on the document having been updated. But I have found that sometimes the document is not updated before my code runs. I assume these services are spun up in their own threads then. My question is, is there a way to trigger my code to run as a result of the service actually completing or do I need to completely override the update service to call my code?

EDIT: To clarify my question, where I call `super.doService(service, response)`, this executes an edit onto the document. Where I have my comment `// Execute other code` I am trying to run some other side effect for the service. This other code relies on the `doService` method to have finished, but `doService` spins off an async task which is not finishing before my other code executes

Comment: am not sure what you mean by "not updated before"? what do you try to do?
e.g. org.eclipse.xtext.web.server.model.UpdateDocumentService.updateDeltaText(XtextWebDocumentAccess, String, int, int) executes async work as well

Comment: I got it to work. Basically I needed it to be sequential, but I wasn't sure where this async task was actually being created and executed. Once I figured that out, I subclassed ServiceDispatcher and UpdateDocumentService so that updateDeltaText() could pass my code to execute in the created async task. I am not sure if this is the "proper" way. I can post the code if you like

Comment: Part of why I had trouble figuring out where that was being done is because of another issue where I cannot view the xtend source in debug mode

Comment: Regarding the debug problem: which Xtext version and build tool do you use?

Comment: xtext 2.15 and gradle 4.9

Comment: Update, I believe the issue has something to do with remote debugging. As I can actually view source when debugging a unit test. I don't think it has anything to do with xtend, but its the default configuration for remote debug that is messed up.